# GWT MaterialListBox- java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: java, gwt

I am using a simple `MaterialListBox` in my code to add some data returned from the server side. Its going fine. But the handler for the particular `MaterialListBox` is not working, its continuosly giving `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I have taken the `MaterialListBox` at my `UiBinder` xml file. In my Java class i just added some items manually for test. But still the change handler is not working, not even the value change handler is working.

I also used the `@UiHandler` code from the GWT material showcase project.

**xml file:**

```
<m:MaterialListBox ui:field="lstBox" />
```

**java class:**

```
lstBox.addItem("key","value");
```

For all the handlers its giving the same error.

1.

```
@UiHandler("lstBox")
void onChangeListBox(ChangeEvent e) {
    MaterialToast.fireToast("Selected Index: " + lstOptions.getSelectedIndex());
}
```

2.

```
lstBox.addHandler(new ChangeHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Window.alert("jbjkvasdbvkjsdabvksdv");
            }
        }, ChangeEvent.getType());
```

3.

```
lstBox.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Window.alert("jbjkvasdbvkjsdabvksdv");
            }
        });
```

All the events giving the same error.
[image: Error on console]
[Gwt material](http://gwtmaterialdesign.github.io/gwt-material-demo/#forms)

Comment: _In my java class i just added some items manually for test_ > Please add that code to your question too. It looks like your listbox is actually empty.

Comment: I had done that too but still its not working

Comment: Your question shows code only for your handlers. You didn't show the code where you are adding the items to the listbox. Please include that code into your question above.